# Trying to make a timeleft with pugjs and momentjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, momentjs

I am trying to make a timeleft in pugjs template engine and momentjs library.

In Add_post.pug the client chooses the duration of the post ( for ex. One day, One week (7 days) or so)

```
 #form-group
    label Duration (Days):
    select.form-control(name='time')
        option.form-control(name='1', value='1') 1 Day
        option.form-control(name='7', value='7') 7 Days
        option.form-control(name='10', value='10') 10 Days
```

I can get the day then I save also the date and time of submission in mongodb like this from server.js:

```
    var time= req.body.time*60*60*24;
    article.time= time;
    article.duration= moment().startOf('second');
```

I am stuck to show this timeleft in my articles.pug view:

```
extends layout
block content
  script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment-with-locales.min.js')
  script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js')   
  ul
    each article, i in articles
      li.list-group-item
        #year
        .box
          .unit Days
          .value
        .box
          .unit Hours
          .value
        .box
          .unit Minutes
          .value
        .box
          .unit Seconds
          .value
- var timeVar = article.time
- var duration= article.duration
script(type='text/javascript', src='/timeleft.js').tick(timeVar , duration);
```

And this is the timeleft.js:

```
   moment().format()
    moment.locale('en-gb')
    function tick(timeVar , duration) {
        var now = Date.now()
        var nextSecond = 1000 - now % 1000
        var year = document.getElementById('year').querySelectorAll('.value')
        var yearArray = moment.duration(duration.diff(now - 1000, 'seconds') + 
        timeVar, 'seconds').format('d H m s', { trim: false }).split(' ')
            yearArray.forEach(function (value, i) {
                if (i === 0) {
                    year[i].textContent = ('00' + value).slice(-3)
                } else {
                    year[i].textContent = ('0' + value).slice(-2)
                }
            })
        setTimeout(tick, nextSecond)
    }
```

I get the error duration.diff is not a function. What I did wrong?. I have a setInterval to delete article automatically after choosed day, but the only thing I want is to show that timeleft in pug view..

I got the timeleft code from this link https://codepen.io/pakastin/pen/GNgqMp?editors=0010 and customised the way I needed..

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing a generated script tag (which goes down to the browser and is loaded or executed there) and a variable that exists in the pug template.

So, this line only loads the timeleft script into the browser and it will never be accessed in the template:

```
script(type='text/javascript', src='/timeleft.js').tick(timeVar , duration);
```

If you really want to import something into your pug template (in my experience you should do this VERY rarely), you need to add that variable to `app.locals` in your app.js file.  This is how you would do that:

```
app.locals.timeleft = require('/timeleft.js');
```

You will then be able to do this in the template:

```
timeleft.tick(timeVar , duration);
```

A much better way to do this is to calculate the timeleft in the route and pass the  variable into the template.  This keeps all logic out of the template where (as you're seeing) it's not easy to write complex code, and the template is only focused on rendering the html.

Comment: Can you give me an example in codepen or replit, I would appreciate it, cause I am new to pug and nodejs

Comment: Codepen can replicate the template, but it can't replicate the route.  I'll expand the answer to explain more details.

Comment: In fact, I think its all okay but the format of the saved date with     article.duration= moment().startOf('second');, and the numbers from     var time= req.body.time*60*60*24;
    article.time= time; are not the same format, so this is the problem, date comes like this "Mon Oct 29 2018 19:14:16 GMT+0100" and the time is "86400" . I am trying to save in same format then it should work..

Comment: I managed to make it without moment.js library. But it doesn't show in each article in my view. I have this:
    each article, i in articles
                span
                  span.days 
                span
                  span.hours 
                span
                  span.minutes 
                span
                  span.seconds 
            script(type='text/javascript')...

Here in script, I have the code but the timeleft is shown only in the first article

Comment: You're probably better off creating a new question or editing this one with those details.